# What are the best blogs for staying up to date on C#, ASP.NET, LINQ, SQL, C++, Ruby, Java, Python?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++, linq, blogs

Apologies if this repeats another - but I couldn't fine one like it.

My day to day programming spans a fair number of technologies: C#, ASP.NET, LINQ / SQL, C++, Ruby, Java, Python in approximately that order.

It's a struggle to keep up to date on any of best practices, new ideas, innovation and improvements, let alone all.

Therefore, what would your top 1 blog be in each of these technologies and which technology do you find easiest to stay up to date with?  I'd have a bias towards blogs with broad and high level rather than narrow and detailed content / solutions / examples.

Answer (score 3):

[InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/) covers most of those subjects, plus you can tailor it to only list the things you are interested in.  I'd suggest the [ADO.NET blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/default.aspx) for Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 3):

I have always rather enjoyed Eric Lippert's blog ["Fabulous Adventures In Coding"](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/). It's not great for staying up to date with the latest technologies but does deal with a lot of the intricacies of C# / .NET. A great site to hone your C# skills.

Answer (score 2):

I like:

- [4 Guys From Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/) for ASP.NET stuff
- [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/) for Ruby on Rails (but I'm new to Rails so it is more tutorial stuff), and
- [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) for process/big picture stuff.
- Of course, Stack Overflow itself is pretty valuable...

Answer (score 1):

Scott Guthrie for ASP.NET, Silverlight and MVC.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/

Answer (score 0):

Python: http://planet.python.org/

Ruby: http://www.rubyflow.com/

Both those links are aggregators, you can often pick up a few more useful blogs etc. from articles posted on those sites.